# How to sum two numbers in Cypher?

Tags: sum, cypher

Given two numeric properties `n.in` and `n.out`, how can I get the sum of them?

My query

```sql
match (n) 
return n.name, id(n), sum(n.in,n.out);
```

But obviously this is false since [`SUM`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/#functions-sum) is for only one property. Looking at [Numeric mathematical functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/mathematical-numeric/) there is no such function too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
match(n)
with sum(n.in + n.out) as sumOfAllNodes
match(n)
return n.name, id(n), n.in + n.out as sumOfaNode, sumOfAllNodes
```

Comment: Thanks. It turns out that the manual I need to look at is [Operators - Neo4j Cypher Manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/operators/#query-operators-mathematical "Operators - Neo4j Cypher Manual")